# Draw content of QOpenGLFramebufferObject onto QOpenGLWidget

Tags: opengl, qt5

I am currently porting from Qt4 to Qt5. While Qt5 still provides the QGLWidget etc. classes, these are to be replaced by QOpenGLWidget etc.

Currently I am drawing complicated stuff into a framebuffer object once. Then I draw it on the screen (into the GL widget) using `drawTexture()` method:

```
target->drawTexture(rect, fb->texture());
```

Afterwards, I overdraw with other temporary things. So whenever I need to update the temporary stuff, I can just re-use the framebuffer object instead of redrawing the complicated stuff.

With QOpenGLWidget, as well as QOpenGLContext, however, there is no convenient `drawTexture()` method anymore. Drawing the texture by-hand with OpenGL would be a minimum of 20 lines of complicated stuff. Textbook stuff, I admit.

Is there any elegant/Qt way of getting my fbo contents onto the screen? For example, it is documented that QOpenGLWidget also uses an fbo as a backend. Instead of drawing the texture, we could also blit the FBOs. But how?

Comment: For performance, you are going to want to do the textured quad. It may take a little bit of extra work to do this, but it's something you write once and can re-use forever. The alternative is `glBlitFramebuffer (...)`, while it sounds like you'd get a performance benefit using a command built specifically to do this, you actually usually get a small penalty and I only use `glBlitFramebuffer (...)` for very special things like copying a renderbuffer object or a multi-sampled buffer into a single-sampled output. If you're drawing into a texture, the best way to display it is to draw a quad.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I also used blitting so far to get from multisampled to regular buffer. I didn't know it was more expensive, good to know.